# Unable to refetch data after mutation with useQuery, useMutation and refetch callback

Tags: jquery, reactjs, apollo-client, graphql-mutation

I have a standard component setup with one component making a query for data and a modal form that mutates entered data on submit. The useQuery hook sets state with the `onCompleted` callback. I've also added a refetch callback in my useQuery hook, pass it down to the form modal and call it `onCompleted` in the useMutation hook. I'm unable to get the data to render immediately without having to refresh the page.

The query:

```
 const {
    loading: childProfilesLoading,
    error: childProfilesError,
    refetch: refetchChildProfiles,
  } = useQuery<any>(GET_CHILD_PROFILES, {
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true, // I was told this might help
    variables: { value: 5 },
    onCompleted: (childProfilesData) =>
      setChildProfiles(childProfilesData?.childProfiles),
  })
```

and the mutation in the modal form:

```
  const [
    createChildProfile,
    { error: createProfileError, loading: createProfilePending },
  ] = useMutation<any>(CREATE_CHILD_PROFILE, {
    onCompleted: () => refetchChildProfiles(),
  })
```

This doesn't add the new data to the parent data in state and doesn't get re-iterated:

```
 {!!childProfiles.length && (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}>
              <Text style={styles.createText}>+ Add child</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
    // ....more jsx data here
```

Comment: it's onSuccess rather than onCompleted no ?

Comment: You got my hopes up there for a second but no, it's `onCompleted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems related to https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3709.

As a workaround, you can rely on the `data` attribute of the query with a useEffect :

```
const {
    loading: childProfilesLoading,
    error: childProfilesError,
    refetch: refetchChildProfiles,
    data: childProfilesData,
  } = useQuery<any>(GET_CHILD_PROFILES, {
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true, // I was told this might help
    variables: { value: 5 },
  })

useEffect(() => {
   setChildProfiles(childProfilesData?.childProfiles),
}, [childProfilesData, setChildProfiles])
```

Or event better, use the `data` attribute directly instead of storing it in another state.

Comment: That's it. Setting state `onCompleted` doesn't work. I just grabbed `data` directly since  `useQuery` fires `onMount`. Works now.